# Solr: AND query strange behaviour, not filtering properly

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am facing strange problem with Solr filter and AND query.
Below is the example for this problem.

> http://localhost:8983/solrcloud/bbconfig/select?indent=on&q=sku:800456652

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<long name="sku">800456652</long>
<long name="parent_store_81_i">1</long>
</doc>
</result>
```

But once I filter on dynamic field "parent_store_81_i", Its returning None.

> http://localhost:8983/solrcloud/bbconfig/select?indent=on&q=parent_store_81_i:1 AND sku:800456652

```
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"> </result>
```

Comment: What is the definition of the dynamic field? Is it indexed or only stored? Does it work if you're only querying the dynamic field?

Comment: Dynamic field is Integer, indexed=True, stored=True

It works perfectly if I query on dynamic field.

Comment: What query parser is in use? Does the result change if you append `defType=lucene`? What does the `defType` value in the response say?